# Example of $\deg(fg)<\deg(f)+\deg(g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, examples-counterexamples

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and $f,g\in R[X_1,...,X_n]$ where $n>1$. What is an example of a pair $f,g$ such that $\deg(fg)<\deg(f)+\deg(g)$?

Moreover, I have proven that the units of $R[X_1,...,X_n]$ are just the units in $R$. (Proof is done inductively) Is it true?

**EDIT**

[image]

Even though the each term in the underlined summation is nonzero, isn't it possible that the summation is 0? Why is this impossible ?

Comment: Does $f = 0$ count? What degree do you attribute to $f = 0$?

Comment: @Moritz No, the degree of $f=0$ is undefined.

Comment: Usually $\deg 0=-\infty$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $R$ is an integral domain, then in fact for any $f,g$ in $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, $\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$. There can only be an inequality over a ring with zero divisors. For instance, let $R$ be the integers mod $6$. Then if $f=2x^2+1$, $g=3x$, we have $fg=6x^3+3x=3x$, in which you can see the desired inequality of degrees.

> If $R$ is an integral domain, then for two polynomials $f,g$ in $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, 
>   $$\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g).$$

Lemma: If $R$ is an integral domain, then $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an integral domain.

I will omit the proof of this, but more can be read [here](http://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Algebra/Section_3.11--Polynomials_Rings_Over_Commutative_Rings.pdf).

Now let $f,g$ be members of $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, with $\deg(f)=k$, $\deg(g)=l$. Define a *leading term* in $f$ to be a term of degree $k$. For instance, if $h=x_1x_2+x_1^2+x_2$, then $h$ has degree $2$ and has two leading terms, $x_1x_2$ and $x_1^2$. Define $f^*$ as the sum over the leading terms of $f$. Continuing our example, $h^*=x_1x_2+x^2$. Note that if $f\in R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $f\neq 0$, then $f^*\in R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $f^*\neq0$.

Now examining the product $fg$, we can see that 
$$
fg=f^*g^*+\text{ remaining terms }.
$$
Since $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is an integral domain, $f^*g^*$ is not equal to zero. But every term in $f^*g^*$ must have degree $k+l$. Moreover, no term in the $(\text{ remaining terms })$ has degree $k+l$, so no cancellation can occur between these two parts. So there will be at least one nonzero term left of degree $k+l$, and $fg$ will have degree $k+l$.

Comment: Seems correct to me thank you